# Problem with deploying addin

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, add-in

I have made a Button addin for ArcMap in Visual Studio 2010, but I don't know how to deploy it.

I tried debugging it from ArcMap but nothing happens.

Comment: Deploy or debug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For deploying without any setup tool, double-click the *.esriAddIn file. This file could be found in the debug folder, after build the project in Visual Studia 2010.
[Add-ins for ArcGIS Desktop 10](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/05/05/add-ins-for-arcgis-desktop-10/)

For deploying a custom component using a setup tool:
[How to deploy a custom component using a setup project](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000016r000000)

Comment: @ Emi :: Thanks for your help, the suggestion was really helpful.

Comment: Now i want to create an addin which launches some windows by clicking a button I've deployed in ArcMap, can you help me with that.

Comment: arcmap add-in button has "OnClick" event. you can show your form or window in this event. 
[sample code:]
protected override void OnClick()
{
      Form1 form = new Form1();
      form.ShowDialog();
}

Comment: click on the right sign beside the answer(not comment)